# Image from database encoded with java webservice and decoded in android. Different results

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, base64

Ok i've googled this topic found couple not really examples but ways to accomplish task similar to mine. So long story told short; i am trying to send an image from database with json string through java webservice, i am comparing byte arrays on each side, they are different, therefore image is not shown.

This is my (restful)webservice code for encoding image with base64

```
dto.setArti_image(new String(Base64.encode(rs.getBlob("arti_image"))));
```

result in byte[]

```
[B@270d42dc
```

And this is my code for decoding

```
byte[] image= Base64.decode(item.getArti_image(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length)                );
```

result in byte

```
[B@41079340
```

Is this correct way of doing it or is there any more reliable way?

Comment: `[B@270d42dc` means `[` Array, `B` => `byte`, `@270d42dc` the object's hashcode. This has nothing to do with it's content. `Arrays.toString` can be used to print the entire content of an array.

Comment: Oh ok, didnt know that, thank you for explanation! Either way bitmapfactory returns SkImageDecoder:: Factory returned null. Just to make clear, is my method of sending image over WS ok?

Comment: Code looks good (assuming the byte array contains compressed image data, like when you dump the content of a .jpg file into a byte array without decoding it). You should probably compare the content and see if it is transferred correctly. If it is, maybe your webservice has corrupt data already. You can also try to download the data into a file, the look at it with regular image viewers. (there are even tools like http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp that can turn base64 string into files, just name it .jpg or whatever it is)

Comment: Thank you! I'll report back tomorrow :)